# What spell did Dolohov use on Hermione in Order of the Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter

What was the spell with purple flame used by Dolohov on Hermione during the Battle at the Department of Mysteries in *Order of the Phoenix*? If Dolohov hadn't been silenced, would it have killed her?

Comment: Was it really revulsion jinx, that made her conscious, and 'quite enough damage to be going on with'? That answer still doesn't justify, as what happens to yaxley after Hermione used it, we don't know.